# What is the correct way to create a custom "project page" for a user?

Tags: javascript, php, user-input

I'm building a web application using React as front-end and PHP/MySQL as back-end. Users should be able to create their own "projects", which can be thought of as an instance of a set of template pages with content that will be customized for the specific project. For example, Facebook pages or Firebase projects have a default template, but instances of them can be created, customized and owned by a user. Something similar to this is what I'm trying to create.

I'm assuming I have a set of default pages that are filled with content stored for the specific project in a database, but I'm unsure of how to best keep track of which project is being visited as the user navigates between the project's pages. I can think of multiple ways of doing this, for example in PHP using GET-variables or session variables, or with JavaScript using local storage variables, but I don't know which one is the most appropriate.

What is the correct way of implementing something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different strategies for implementing this functionality. I've seen web applications that do everything from setting a cookie or session variable to keep track of which project is being viewed to using POST parameters, but by far the most common way is GET parameters, e.g. `project.php?project_id=7`. If you don't like the look of that, you could always use URL rewriting so you could use something like `user/project/7`.

If you absolutely have to keep the URLs identical across all projects, your next best option would be session variables or cookies, which would require having an intermediate page that sets the cookie or variable and then redirecting to the project page.

Based on this, you can then query the database to fetch the layout information for that specific template and then render it with React or whichever framework you are using.

If your template pages are highly customizable, it will get cumbersome to have a separate page for each one. You tagged your question with `php`, so I assume you are planning on using PHP to achieve this behavior. Excellent! That's just the sort of thing it's made for. I don't know anything about your project setup, but depending on the size of your application you could either break it down into the smallest set of customizable components and conditionally render whichever one is applicable, or else inline each option directly into your PHP code. I'm also not sure how exactly you are incorporating React into this, but the basic thought process is the same.

Comment: This clarified it a lot for me, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mention what you're building the application with, but you are basically talking about "views" which display information based on the user access and the page that they are viewing.

I'll quote a page from angular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

> To add the detailed view, we are going to turn index.html into what we call a    > "layout template". This is a template that is common for all views in our          > application. Other "partial templates" are then included into this layout        > template depending on the current "route" — the view that is currently displayed > to the user.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add that I'm planning to build it in React.